# broadcast Latitude and Longitude to android users through C#

Tags: c#, android, web-services, google-maps

Sending Latitude and Longitude to Android app is problem for me. How can we send Latitude and Longitude to the registered android users? should I need to work on socket programming or we can achieve this goal through web services?

An Android user in taxi sending his location (Latitude and Longitude) to the server (web service/ or socket which ever suits subjected scenario) and these Latitude and Longitude should be broadcast to all other Android users so they can see continuously moving taxi on google map.

Can anybody help me on this issue that how can we achieve this scenario? Can It be done with web service/socket programming? How to send messages to the other android user from windows based server with C# code.

Thanks

Comment: there are basically two ways: 1) you can broadcast the data using signalR 2). create an API to be polled by mobile device at particular interval.

Answer (score 0):

there are basically two ways:
 1) you can broadcast the data using signalR
 2). create an API to be polled by mobile device at particular interval

For real time communication, signalR could be the best approach.

These are some links which may help you.
[SignalR](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/an-introduction-to-real-time-communication-with-signalr/) &
[How to use signalR in android and ios Apps.](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/how-to-use-signalr-in-ios-and-android-apps.aspx)